# Как получить первый ближайший сверху элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как-то можно получить текст с соответствующего тега `b` с классом `title`? То есть, при клике на второй селект должно отображаться слово "Мяч", при клике на первый - "Кинг"

Единственная зацепка, которую я нашёл, - это искать первый верхний элемент с таким классом.

```js
$('input.test').click(function(){
  var pays = $('.payment_type :selected');
  $.each(pays, function(){
    console.log($(this.parentNode.parentNode).text())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="cell product">
  <b class="title">Кинг</b> - 2 шт; <b>Доставка:</b> Курьером;
  <b>Оплата:</b>
  <select style="width: 130px" class="payment_type">
    <option value="1" data-codename="btc">BTC</option>
    <option value="2" data-codename="blago">blago</option>
    <option value="3" data-codename="card">Картой</option>
    <option value="4" data-codename="cash">Безналичный</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <hr width="60%">

  <b class="title">Мяч</b> - 1 шт; <b>Доставка:</b> Курьером;
  <b>Оплата:</b>
  <select style="width: 130px" class="payment_type">
    <option value="2" data-codename="blago">blago</option>
    <option value="3" data-codename="card">Картой</option>
    <option value="4" data-codename="cash">Безналичный</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, нужно разделить блоки и искать отталкиваясь от того, в каком блоке произошло событие:

```
$(this).closest('.product').find('.title');
```

```js
$('input.test').click(function() {
  const productEl = $(this).closest('.product');
  const titleEl = productEl.find('.title');
  console.log(titleEl.text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cell product">
  <b class="title">Кинг</b> - 2 шт; <b>Доставка:</b> Курьером;
  <b>Оплата:</b>
  <select style="width: 130px" class="payment_type">
    <option value="1" data-codename="btc">BTC</option>
    <option value="2" data-codename="blago">blago</option>
    <option value="3" data-codename="card">Картой</option>
    <option value="4" data-codename="cash">Безналичный</option>
  </select>
  <input class=test type=button value=Test />
</div>
<br>
<hr width="60%">
<div class="cell product">
  <b class="title">Мяч</b> - 1 шт; <b>Доставка:</b> Курьером;
  <b>Оплата:</b>
  <select style="width: 130px" class="payment_type">
    <option value="2" data-codename="blago">blago</option>
    <option value="3" data-codename="card">Картой</option>
    <option value="4" data-codename="cash">Безналичный</option>
  </select>
  <input class=test type=button value=Test />
</div>
```

Comment: Была такая мысль. Если ничего другого не придумаю, приму Ваш вариант.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 а тут нечего думать, это верный вариант